# Add Control Section Only For The Top Section - Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to add a custom tab to only for the top Section widget, but when I call start_controls_section, the settings shows up for both top Section and inner Sections.

I tried to dig in the Javascript side as well but no success.

Is there a way to create a settings tab only for the top section but not for inner sections?

```
add_action( 'elementor/element/section/section_layout/after_section_end', array( $this, 'RegisterSectionControls' ), 10, 2 );

public function RegisterSectionControls( $element, $sectionId ) {

      $element->start_controls_section('my_section',
            [
                'label'         => __('My Section'),
                'tab'           => Controls_Manager::TAB_LAYOUT
            ]
        );

        $element->add_control('my_switcher',
            [
                'label'         => __( 'Enable'),
                'type'          => Controls_Manager::SWITCHER,
                'return_value'  => 'yes',
                'prefix_class'  => 'my-section-prefix-',
                'render_type'   => 'template'
            ]
        );

        $element->end_controls_section();
    }
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can use this -

'hide_in_inner' => true,

Regards,